# About correct notation of pareto dominance in optimization

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I search the correct notation of Pareto Dominance, but i don't know if it is a question for [Mathexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or here..

In multiple papers, like the classic [Deb nsga2 paper](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iitk.ac.in%2Fkangal%2FDeb_NSGA-II.pdf&ei=eoHYVKPkPMbPaN3EgaAB&usg=AFQjCNF-9q4AEdFvO0AWhYPq1I1qpBMpiw&sig2=aWANKYZE5jIhwMW0t1IOrQ&bvm=bv.85464276,d.d2s), you can found the pareto dominance relation written like this

A dominate B if

[image]

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency), or other paper, like [this one of Zitler](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fe-collection.library.ethz.ch%2Feserv%2Feth%3A25454%2Feth-25454-01.pdf&ei=6YHYVP7gN8y9aavcgZgH&usg=AFQjCNG7SGLt3Y7XcN88zoVD9fETDFRC_A&sig2=QEuN0u6mblmsOWpVR9wYVg), you find another notation :

A dominate B if

[image]

What is the best and correct mathematic notation here ?
What is the exact name of this symbol ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

≺ is called [precedes](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=227A), ≻ [succeeds](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=227B&B1=Show).

According to the well known [Evolutionary Optimization Algorithms](https://books.google.it/books?id=gwUwIEPqk30C&redir_esc=y) the standard notation for A dominates B is A ≻ B:

> 20.1 Pareto Optimality
>
> [...]
>
> Domination: a point *x*<sup>*</sup> is said to dominate *x* if the following two conditions hold:
>
> 1. f<sub>i</sub>(*x*<sup>*</sup>) <= f<sub>i</sub>(*x*) for all *i* ∈ [1,*k*]
> 2. f<sub>i</sub>(*x*<sup>*</sup>) < f<sub>i</sub>(*x*) for at least one *j* ∈ [1,*k*]
>
> that is *x*<sup>*</sup> is at least as good as *x* for all objective function values and it's better than *x* for at least one objective function value. We use the notation:
>
> *x*<sup>*</sup> ≻ *x*
>
> to indicate that *x*<sup>*</sup> dominates *x*.
>
> This notation can be confusing because the symbol ≻ looks like a
>   "greater than" symbol but since we deal mainly with minimization problems,
>   the symbol ≻ means the function values of *x*<sup>*</sup> are less than
>   or equal to those of *x*.
>
> **However this notation is standard in the
>   literature**, so this is the notation that we use.

However even the reverse notation is used (probably "to avoid" the confusion the author refers to!)